# Delphi xe4 - How can I access Foursquare API via HTTP

Tags: ios, delphi, mobile, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

I have delphi xe4 and I need to know how can I access Foursquare API via HTTP like
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?ll=-23,-47&venuePhotos=1&section=food&client_id=Xxxxxxxxxx&client_secret=yyyyyyyyy&v=20120321

to Firemonkey Mobile IOS

Answer (score 3):

Indy 10.6 ships with XE4 and is usable in iOS.  You can use Indy's `TIdHTTP` component, eg:

```
var
  Response: String;

Response := IdHTTP1.Get('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?ll=-23,-47&venuePhotos=1&section=food&client_id=Xxxxxxxxxx&client_secret=yyyyyyyyy&v=20120321');
```

Because you want to use HTTPS on iOS, that complicates the situation.  Normally, you can assign a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` component to the `TIdHTTP.IOHandler` property before sending a request.  But Indy normally uses OpenSSL dynamic libs, and iOS does not allow dynlibs to be used in apps, so OpenSSL has to be compiled into your app statically instead.  You would have to compile the static version of OpenSSL yourself (Embarcadero cannot ship it) and add it to your iOS project, then add the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders_static` unit to your `uses` clause.

If you don't want to use Indy, you will have to use Apple's own HTTP(S) APIs instead:

[Making HTTP and HTTPS Requests](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests.html)